# Weird symbols on a comment

Tags: support

I see some weird symbols on the 3rd comment in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23028957/remove-space-between-anchor-tag).

Is it a fault with my OS or browser? What is it?

[image]

Comment: Unicode supports some pretty crazy stuff. Adeno has [done it deliberately](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Zalgo)

Comment: http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/zalgo; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: N҉á̧͘h̸̡͞! ̶I͏t̶́͜'s̡̕ ̨͜ņ̷͠o҉̴͘t́ ̴͢t̡̀h̸a̸̧̕t̛ ̕͟w͢è̸̶ì̕r̀̕d̕͏ ̴a͘͘͜f҉t̛҉ę̷r̨͟ ̷҉҉à̷͡ĺ̶l̡.̡

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a bug, just someone exploring the limits of whats supported.

This particular corrupted text + "he comes" is generally associated with Zalgo, an [Internet meme](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Zalgo).

H͜e wh̕o W̴̖ͅa̶̙̞͇̳it̩̖͈͖̝̰s̘̙̱̲̲͔̘͘ ̲͈̘̪̲̦̮͢B͓̦̗̭e͇͓̤̝̺hi͖̞̪̦̙͙n̲͖̗̗̩͖͟d͉ ̞́ ̜ͭT̯̻̾́̀͂͊ͧȟ͕̩̗̻̬̘̀ͣ̊̈́̽ͅe̘͔̭̥̼͆͛̆͂͑̆̇ ̣̤͓͎̼̭̩̄ͯ͒͟Wͪͩͯͪ̉͐͏̮͕̩̖̦ḁ̠̘̙̎ͧl̼̋̃l͓͍͍̫̺̘̪̔.̝͖̂͋͠

̳̺ͥͫ͛̕Z̦͓̰̟͔̰̐͂̏ͨ͒͆̇ͅḀ̲͔̖̩̈́̍͝L̗ͩͬ͗G͍͔̙̘̣͟O̧̹!̵͈͓̜̯̹͉ͧ̈̏

[He comes](http://eeemo.net/)

Comment: It's my first, I didn't know. Should SO allow that?

Comment: @Amar doesn't really hurt to have it available.  If it's misused you can flag but usually its not. Its usually used for S̼͎̹̺̗̻̝t͚̝r͔͠ạ͈͇̜̲͍ṇ̸̠̟̱͕ge̮̠͕ ̦̬̪̘̙̣a͍n̛̳d̠̹̪̠̳͖̜͢ ̱̹͖͎̫u̯͎̝̩n̴̼na͙͚̤̣̖t͕͇̬̰͝u̟r̡̠̟a̶͇͔͙l̦̪ a̖͔͙̞̖̥c̴̖t̜s̢̟̘

Comment: Ok, i͍̫̜̥̻̰̯͘f͓̘͍͙͠ ̰̼y̬̥̬̯͈o̫̳u̘̥̬͙͖̞͎̕ ͙͈̲͇s̨̲̯̱͈̩a̮̺̞̭̲͙̭y ̶̹͓͈̯s̴o̘̝͉͕̥͡ :)

Comment: @AmarDuplantier it's not really possible to block it, without blocking legitimate things.

Comment: Your last link captures the key point exquisitely, sir: I salute you!  ***Zalgo delenda est.***